# Results from a survey to be shown as progress bar

Tags: php, codeigniter, progress, survey, onactivityresult

I have a survey and I want to show results from it as progress bars. I have done it for one question, but I don't know how to do it when questions are 40 and more, I need some logic not to write much code. And also I have to show these results in this way: if you have voted for example for Question 1 with 5 points, results to show percentage of how many people have voted with 5 points for the same questions. This is my model:

```html
<?php
class Result_model extends CI_Model {

    
    public function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->database();
         
    }
     
    public function total_rows()
    {
     $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM survey_answers ");
      if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                return $query->num_rows();
            } 
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }
    }
    public function result_question()
    {
     $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM survey_answers WHERE question_id = 3 ");
      if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                return $query->num_rows();
            } 
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }
    }

    




}
```

My controller:

```html
 public function results_show()
    {
        $this->load->model('result_model'); 
        $data['total_rows'] =$this->result_model->total_rows();
        $data['result_question1'] = $this->result_model->result_question();
        $data['view'] = 'results';
        
        $this->load->view('templates/main',$data);  
    }
```

My view is:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class='col-md-8'>
<br/><br/>
<?php
$percentQuestion1 = ($result_question1 / $total_rows)*100;
?>

<ul>
 <br />
 <div class="progress">
     <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: <?php echo round($percentQuestion1,2); ?>%;">
       <?php echo round($percentQuestion1,2); ?>%
     </div>
 </div>
   
</ul>

<h6>Total votes: <?php echo $total_rows ?></h6>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My survey view is:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<br/><br/>
<?php
$survey_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

 echo "<div class='col-md-9'>";

echo "<table border='0'>";   
echo validation_errors();

foreach ($survey as $row)
{
 echo "<tr>";
 echo form_open('index/survey_fill/' .$survey_id);
    echo "<td class='col-md-9'>"; 
 echo "$row->question";
 echo "<input type='hidden' name='question_id' value='$row->question_id' />";
 echo "</td>";
 if($this->session->userdata('role_id')==4) {
  "</tr><tr><td>";  
 $data=array(
  'name' =>  'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
  'value' => '5'
 );
   echo "<input type='hidden' name='survey_id' value='$row->survey_id'>";
 echo "<input type='hidden' name='question_id' value='$row->question_id' />";
 echo form_radio($data);
 echo " I like it very much ";
 $data=array(
  'name' =>  'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
  'value' => ' 4'
 );
 echo form_radio($data);
 echo " I like it ";
 $data=array(
  'name' => 'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
  'value' => ' 3'
 );
 echo form_radio($data);
 echo " I like it little ";
 $data=array(
  'name' => 'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
  'value' => '2'
 );
 echo form_radio($data);
 echo " I don't like ";
 $data=array(
  'name' => 'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
  'value' => '1'
 );
 echo form_radio($data);
 echo " I don't like at all ";
 echo "</td></tr><tr><td>";
   
}

 $data=array(
  'name' => 'submit',
  'value' => 'Send',
   'id' => 'survey_submit'
 );
 echo form_submit($data);
 echo "</td></tr>";
 echo form_close();
 echo "</table>";
 echo "</div>";
 echo "</body>";
 echo "</html>";
```

Comment: display a bar graphic with CSS and the 100% of the container is 100% progress and then assign the size based on progression, so 20 results would be `(20/40)*100 = 50% = $w` so then your progress bar would be `CSS width:$w;`

Comment: I have edites my question, I added the survey and description how these progress bars should look like.